# Deriving class from `object` in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

So I'm just learning python (I know plenty of other languages) and I'm confused about something. I think this is due to lack of documentation (at least that I could find). On a few websites, I've read that you should derive your classes from `object`:

```
class Base(object):
    pass
```

But I don't see what that does or why or when you should do it. Is there official documentation on this that I've missed? Is this a 3.x feature?

Comment: I looked here http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Mostly it isn't going to matter whether or not you inherit from object, but if you don't there are bugs waiting to catch you out when you've forgotten that you decided not to bother.

Some subtle things just won't work properly if you don't ultimately inherit from object:

1. Using properties in classic classes only partly works: `get` works alright, but `set` does weird things.
2. Multiple inheritance behaves differently in classic classes than in classes derived from object.
3. Also multiple inheritance won't work if you try to mix classic classes with those that subclass object. Whatever you do you want to be consistent.

Some people are fine with continuing to use classic classes except when they need the new behaviour, others say to always use new style classes to avoid later shooting yourself in the foot. If you're working on a single person project do whatever is good for you; if its a shared project be consistent with the other developers.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up a lot. I wish this was documented better

Answer (score 11):

In Python 3, classes extend object implicitly, whether you say so yourself or not.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374857/should-all-python-classes-extend-object#answer-15374884).

Answer (score 8):

Start here: http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/

Also, read this: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html

It is one of several Python 2 interim solutions that will no longer be needed in version 3.