# Should all Python classes extend object?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have found that both of the following work:

```
class Foo():
    def a(self):
        print "hello"

class Foo(object):
    def a(self):
        print "hello"
```

Should all Python classes extend object? Are there any potential problems with not extending object?

Comment: Is there a difference between `class Foo():` and `class Foo:`? As I observe, both work in Python 3.

Comment: It's well answered in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object

Answer (score 129, accepted):

In Python 2, not inheriting from `object` will create an old-style class, which, amongst other effects, causes `type` to give different results:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
... 
>>> type(Foo())
<type 'instance'>
```

vs.

```
>>> class Bar(object): pass
... 
>>> type(Bar())
<class '__main__.Bar'>
```

Also the rules for multiple inheritance are [different](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) in ways that I won't even try to summarize here. All good documentation that I've seen about MI describes new-style classes.

Finally, old-style classes have disappeared in Python 3, and inheritance from `object` has become implicit. So, always prefer new style classes unless you need backward compat with old software.

Answer (score 76):

In Python 3, classes extend `object` implicitly, whether you say so yourself or not.

In Python 2, there's [old-style and new-style](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/node33.html) classes. To signal a class is new-style, you have to inherit explicitly from `object`. If not, the old-style implementation is used.

You generally want a new-style class. Inherit from `object` explicitly. Note that this also applies to Python 3 code that aims to be compatible with Python 2.

Comment: Yes, the difference [Free Foo pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15374901/2932052), has gone, BTW: [are the empty parentheses optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374857/should-all-python-classes-extend-object#comment66528880_15374857)

Comment: There is a lot of python 3 code that uses foo(object):. Is this just a convention then?

Comment: @RFVenter It may be code that's supposed to run under both Python 2 and 3, in which case you need to subclass object explicitly in order to make the class behave largely the same under Python 2.

Comment: @blubberdiblub That is what I suspected BUT our project is running exclusively on python 3.5 virtualenv. I think the code must have been copied from a python 2 project.

Comment: @RFVenter yup, that may be another explanation. And of course, if it's Python 3.x only now, it's fine to get rid of the object references.

Answer (score 16):

In python 3 you can create a class in three different ways & internally they are all equal (see examples). It doesn't matter how you create a class, all classes in python 3 inherits from special class called  **object**. The  class **object**  is fundamental class in python and provides lot of functionality like double-underscore methods, descriptors, super() method, property() method etc.

Example 1.

```
class MyClass:
 pass
```

Example 2.

```
class MyClass():
 pass
```

Example 3.

```
class MyClass(object):
  pass
```

Comment: This is not strictly true... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238606/is-it-necessary-or-useful-to-inherit-from-pythons-object-in-python-3-x/45893772#45893772

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. And yes, probably not relevant to most people up until it is relevant.

Comment: @PhilipAdler It's commonly assumed that `object` makes reference to built-in `object`. If we must take into account that any CPython's built-in identifier can be replaced we could barely make some assertion about the data model. Can it be seriously argued that `str` does not always accept a string as an argument because one could assign `builtins.str = None`?

Comment: I keep seeing this claim that this is "widely assumed", and I accept that it is an assumption that every current implementation makes (it is not a requirement of the language), it has not been my experience that the majority of python programmers I have met assume this, know about it, or have even considered it. Regardless of which, the assertion that it is commonly assumed, even if true, does not invalidate my assertion that the equivalence is not _strictly_ true.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have covered, Python 3 inheritance from object is implicit.  But they do not state what you should do and what is convention.

The Python 3 documentation examples all use the following style which is convention, so I suggest you follow this for any future code in Python 3.

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Example quote:

> Class objects support two kinds of operations: attribute references
>   and instantiation.
>
> Attribute references use the standard syntax used for all attribute
>   references in Python: obj.name. Valid attribute names are all the
>   names that were in the class’s namespace when the class object was
>   created. So, if the class definition looked like this:
>
> ```
> class MyClass:
>     """A simple example class"""
>     i = 12345
>
>     def f(self):
>         return 'hello world'
> ```

Another quote:

> Generally speaking, instance variables are for data unique to each
>   instance and class variables are for attributes and methods shared by
>   all instances of the class:
>
> ```
> class Dog:
>
>     kind = 'canine'         # class variable shared by all instances
>
>     def __init__(self, name):
>         self.name = name    # instance variable unique to each instance
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all Python classes should extend (or rather subclass, this is Python here) object. While normally no serious problems will occur, in some cases (as with multiple inheritance trees) this will be important. This also ensures better compatibility with Python 3.

Comment: exactly, technically if you don't you will get a classic class, but there are no real advantages to this and it isn't supported by python 3 anyway

Comment: I'm curious about why it improve compatibility with python3. To my understanding, python3 will make it extend object automatically even if u don't specify it, right?

Comment: @PaulLo Right, but if you explicitly inherit from object, you will get the same (new-style) behavior on both Python 2 and Python 3. It isn't a matter of changing how Python 3 works, it's a matter of using forward-compatibility on Python 2.

Comment: This suggestion looks not very elegant, but in case you address Python2 and Python3, it seems effective. But how relevant is it in practice?

Comment: @Wolf It depends on what you're doing. If you have complex inheritance trees, it matters quite a lot. If you want your class to be a descriptor, you have to use new-style. You can follow the links from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python if you want more in-depth information.

Answer (score 0):

in python3 there isn't a differance, but in python2 not extending `object` gives you an old-style classes; you'd like to use a new-style class over an old-style class.

Comment: This answer is reasonable, but other answerers got there faster and/or in better detail; this answer isn't adding any value to the page as it stands.