# Incomplete Object in Python Tutor?

Tags: python, string, list, queue

I have this training exercise where I need to find the problems in this program. I can't find them and python tutor does not allow me to see the object created. It just says incomplete object.  The program should create a kind of queue for strings.  What is wrong with the code?

```
class A():
"""Eine Art Warteschlange für Strings"""

    def __init__(self, wait = [], now = ""):
        self.wait = wait
        self.now = now

    def new_string(self, x):
        """Fügt einen String zur Warteschlange hinzu"""
        self.wait.append(str(x))

    def next_string(self):
        """Holt den nächsten String aus der Warteschlange, speichert ihn als aktuellen String"""
        self.now = self.wait[0]
        self.wait.pop(0)

    def top(self):
        """Gibt den aktuellen String zurück"""
        return self.now

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top
```

Comment: Can you share the error and traceback for the error you are getting?

Comment: At a first glance the only thing I notice that you should write class(object) in order to extends object. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374857/should-all-python-classes-extend-object

Comment: theres no error, the program is just not doing what it should,
the now string is always empty

Comment: @Lauch30000 Which Python version are you using ?

Comment: @Lauch30000 : How do you call the class? What output do you expect? What output does it give you?

Comment: @al27091 Inheritance from `object` is implicit in Python3

Comment: I'm using python3
for example:
a = A()
a = a.new_string("examplestring")
a.next_string()
print(a.top)
This should return "examplestring"

Comment: @Lauch30000 Can you reflect this by editing your question or adding a relevant tag?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the few bugs I came across in your class.(There may be more):

- Under indentation of the class docs.
  Fix: Indent it by 4 spaces to the right.
- The `__str__` magic method doesn't return a `string`.
  Fix: Replace `self.top` with `self.top()`. You would want to return the  value returned by the method `top`.
- Not updating the attribute `now` whenever `new_string` is added.
  Since, you are using the object's `now` attribute in `__str__`, it is advisable to update it whenever an empty object is initialised using `new_string` method. There are several ways to do. I would suggest you fix this as you see fit.

Example:

```
In []: a = A()
In []: a.new_string('foo')
In []: print(a)

In []: a.now
Out[]: ''
In []: a.wait
Out[]: ['foo']
```