# Is it possible to use python decorators to direct specific unit tests toward different instances of what is being tested?

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator, python-unittest

I have a class that contains XML strings. These are my models.

```
class ContainerForStringXMLs():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def get_model1(self):
        return """I'm a long string called model1"""

    @staticmethod
    def get_model2(self):
        return """I'm a long string called model2"""
```

I have a base test class which gives me access to the models in my other tests (and a few other things which aren't important here)

```
class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self, model='model1'):
        self.model=model

        if self.model == 'model1':
            self.test_model = ContainerForStringXMLs.model1()
        elif self.model == 'model2':
            self.test_model = ContainerForStringXMLs.model2()

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.model
        del self.test_model
```

And my actual test class looks something like this:

```
class TestClass(BaseTest):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test_on_model1(self):
        """
        I want to perform this test on model1
        """
        print self.test_model ##would return model 1

    def test_on_model2(self):
        """
        I want to perform this test on model 2 
        """
        print self.testmodel2
```

The test I want to perform is exactly the same test but the models are different and therefore the values that I pull from the xml will be different in each case. My question is: is there a nice pythonic way to switch between models from the TestClass? I was thinking perhaps a decorator or some sort?

It'd be great if I was able to use something like the following to choose which model I direct the test toward:

```
class TestClass(BaseTest):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @testmodel1
    def test_on_model1(self):
        """
        I want to perform this test on model1
        """
        print self.test_model ##would return model 1

    @testmodel2    
    def test_on_model2(self):
        """
        I want to perform this test on model 2 
        """
        print self.testmodel2
```

Is this sort of behavior possible?

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand why you want to do this. Why is `@testmodel1` before a test def preferable to `self.test_model = ContainerForStringXMLs.model1()` inside the test def? Or better yet, pull out the testing of separate models into separate test cases and then override `setUp` to use the appropriate model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“XML strings” class is in `models.py` as-is.
Testing helpers (base class and decorator) are in `testutils.py`:

```
import unittest
import functools

import models


class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self, model='model1'):
        self.model_loader = models.ContainerForStringXMLs
        self.model = model

    @property
    def model_contents(self):
        return getattr(
            self.model_loader, 'get_' + self.model)(self.model_loader)


def use_model(model):
    """Make BaseTestCase-aware test use particular model."""
    def _wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def _inner(self):
            orig = self.model
            self.model = model
            func(self)
            self.model = orig
        return _inner
    return _wrapper
```

`use_model` is a decorator that takes model name (`model`), and
temporarily sets `self.model` for test method. `model_contents`
is a property that gets XML string from `ContainerForStringXMLs`
for current `self.model`.

As `get_model1` and `get_model2` are static methods that take `self`
(in your example), in `model_contents` I pass `ContainerForStringXMLs`
class as `self` (that’s not particularly good). If that is not what
you want, change `(self.model_loader)` to something else (and, of
course, change `get_*` methods in `ContainerForStringXMLs` to match
the way you call them). Given that this is a minor issue, I just assumed
that only tests and `BaseTest` may be modified.

In `test_models.py` there are two test cases:

```
from testutils import BaseTestCase, use_model


class TwoModelsWithDefaultModelTest(BaseTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        BaseTestCase.setUp(self, model='model2')

    @use_model('model1')
    def test_first_model(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.model, 'model1')
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model_contents,
            "I'm a long string called model1")

    def test_second_model(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.model, 'model2')
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model_contents,
            "I'm a long string called model2")

    @use_model('model1')
    def test_first_model_again(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.model, 'model1')
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model_contents,
            "I'm a long string called model1")

    def test_second_model_again(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.model, 'model2')
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model_contents,
            "I'm a long string called model2")


class TwoModelsTestWithoutExplicitSetUp(BaseTestCase):

    @use_model('model1')
    def test_first_model(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.model, 'model1')
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model_contents,
            "I'm a long string called model1")

    @use_model('model2')
    def test_second_model(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.model, 'model2')
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model_contents,
            "I'm a long string called model2")

    def test_first_model_again(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.model, 'model1')
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model_contents,
            "I'm a long string called model1")

    @use_model('model2')
    def test_second_model_again(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.model, 'model2')
        self.assertEqual(
            self.model_contents,
            "I'm a long string called model2")
```

`TwoModelsWithDefaultModelTest` calls `BaseTestCase.setUp`
to set `self.model` to `'model2'` for tests that do not use
`use_model` decorator. `TwoModelsTestWithoutExplicitSetUp` uses
default implementation of `BaseTestCase.setUp` without changing
`model` argument default, so there default `self.model` is `'model1'`.

---

Judging by `print` statements, you use Python 2. You
[should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15374901/149069) make
`ContainerForStringXMLs` inherit from `object`.