# How can I call a method from base class

Tags: python, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        print("test")

    def first_func(self):
        print("first function call")


class Deriv(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)

    def first_func(self):
        print("Test Derived")

C = Deriv()
C.first_func() # It gives output "Test Derived"
```

How can I call a first_func() method (output should be "first function call") from base class ( Class Base) using only object C and python 2.7 ?

Comment: You are currently doing something called "overriding" a method. Check this [article](http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/05/19/method-overriding-in-python/) out for more information about it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Base.first_func(C)` to explicitly call the base class function:

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        print("test")

    def first_func(self):
        print("first function call")


class Deriv(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)

    def first_func(self):
        print("Test Derived")

C = Deriv()
Base.first_func(C)
```

Output is:

```
test
first function call
```

If you were [using new-style classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384374/deriving-class-from-object-in-python) (ie., you had derived `Base` from `object`), using `super` is preferred, as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747397/calling-base-class-method-in-python).